# Can not connect wirelessly to internet in CrunchBang 10

Tags: wifi, internet, crunchbang

I am trying to install Crunch Bang 10 on a clients computers. The problem is, wireless internet is not working. Internet on the computer has worked before when it had Lubuntu on it. I have wired works. The computer could temporaily be connected with a wire to do the fix,  but it can not be permanent. The output from `lspci` (I saw at http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-find-wireless-driver-chipset/ it told you some wireless info.)

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 82845 845 [Brookdale] Chipset Host Bridge (rev 04)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82845 845 [Brookdale] Chipset AGP Bridge (rev 04)
00:1d.0 USB Controller: Intel Corporation 82801CA/CAM USB Controller #1 (rev 02)
00:1e.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801 Mobile PCI Bridge (rev 42)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation 82801CAM ISA Bridge (LPC) (rev 02)
00:1f.1 IDE interface: Intel Corporation 82801CAM IDE U100 Controller (rev 02)
00:1f.5 Multimedia audio controller: Intel Corporation 82801CA/CAM AC'97 Audio Controller (rev 02)
00:1f.6 Modem: Intel Corporation 82801CA/CAM AC'97 Modem Controller (rev 02)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: ATI Technologies Inc Radeon Mobility M7 LW [Radeon Mobility 7500]
02:00.0 Ethernet controller: 3Com Corporation 3c905C-TX/TX-M [Tornado] (rev 78)
02:01.0 CardBus bridge: Texas Instruments PCI1420 PC card Cardbus Controller
02:01.1 CardBus bridge: Texas Instruments PCI1420 PC card Cardbus Controller
02:03.0 CardBus bridge: Texas Instruments PCI1410 PC card Cardbus Controller (rev 01)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you haven't got one of the [3.2 kernel backports](http://transmissionboards.com/tech/crunchbang-linux-wireless-not-working-t249.html), you might need to do that to get the necessary drivers.